# Sending a link to another android phone via SMS

Tags: java, android, gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I am developing an application where I have to send the `coordinates of the latitude and longitude to another android phone in the form of the link` such that when they click on that link,a google map with that location will open up.

I have thoroughly `search for google Maps` but I havenot find anything satisfactorily that will fulfill my objective.

thanks in advance!!

I have tried to doing like this..

```
SmsManager smsManager= SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneno, null, "This is my location"+latitude+" "+longitude+"I need ur       Help!!", null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, it's in the webapps section but it should give you the answer you're looking for I think:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/create-a-google-maps-link-to-a-specific-location